# Is it better to simply return than throwing an exception

Tags: java

I'm bit confused to choose between simply return or throwing an exception from a method.
For example, I have a method m1 which takes Plan as an argument:

```
public void m1(final Plan plan){
      if(plan==null){
       log.trace("received null plan.");
       return;
     }
}
```

OR

```
public void m1(final Plan plan){
   if(plan==null){
      throw new IllegalArgumentException("received null plan."); 
   }
}
```

Q1. Which is better here?
Q2. When to actually return from code OR throw an exception ?

Comment: Depends on how critical it is for your method i.e. `m1` to receive a `null` Plan.

Comment: It really depends on what the rest of your code looks like, and who/what would be calling this method.  If the `null` is a critical error, then an exception is warranted.

Comment: Is it _normal_ for `plan` to be `null`? Do what you needed to, return normally. (e.g. initialising `Child(father, mother)` for an orphan - parents being `null` is exactly what you want). Is it _abnormal_ for `plan` to be `null`? Throw an exception. (e.g. `employee.pay(salary)` where you can pay 0 but you can't pay and not pay at the same time, so `null` argument means you're doing something dumb.) Only you can know which case you have.

Comment: On the other hand, voting to close this as opinion based.

Comment: @nullpointer I'd say the question is looking for an opinion-based answer, but there is actually an objectively good answer, repeated in various forms by all the responders here (including you).

Comment: It entirely depends of what method `m1` is supposed to do. The method name is really bad and non-descriptive. Name your methods so they correctly state what they are doing, which usually means at least a verb, e.g. `get`, `do`, `process`, `open`, `close`, `print`, `save`, ...

Comment: Thanks for asking. I have seen way too many methods tacitly returning when receiving an unexpected null. Programs with such methods may be hell to test and debug.

Answer (score 4):

## Depends on your situation

There is no “better” here. Which is appropriate depends on the context of the business problem and the design of your API.

The essential problem is that a NULL have at least two very different meanings:

- Missing value, by mistake.
- Value intentionally omitted.

You have to decide in your particular situation what is tolerable.

In some API, there may be a method that takes, say, three arguments. Depending on the values of the first two arguments, the third may be irrelevant. Expecting a NULL is appropriate. Some would say this is an awkward design, but that is a different question. As far as a NULL being acceptable, that may be reasonable in such a case.

## `Objects`

The [`Objects`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Objects.html) class in Java has [static methods](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html) to help out here.

### Check if null or not

Convenience methods for checking if an object reference is null.

```
public void doIt( Plan plan ) {
    if( Objects.isNull( plan ) ) { … }   // If `plan` is null.
    …
}
```

…or is *not* null.

```
public void doIt( Plan plan ) {
    if( Objects.nonNull( plan ) ) { … }  // If `plan` is not null.
    …
}
```

### Throw `NullPointerException`

A convenience method will take care of throwing an exception on your behalf, if that is what you want.

```
public void doIt( Plan plan ) {
    Plan p = Objects.requireNotNull( plan ) ;  // Throws a `NullPointerException`.
    …
}
```

Optionally write a message.

```
public void doIt( Plan plan ) {
    Plan p = Objects.requireNotNull( plan , "A Plan must be passed, null is not acceptable. Message # b8ad169f-dab6-414f-8728-c50a13a48dbb." ) ;  // Throws a `NullPointerException`.
    …
}
```

### Fallback to default

Sometimes a method can fall back to a default value when receiving a NULL. Imagine your `Plan` class offering a `static final` constant object named `BASIC_PLAN`.

```
public void doIt( Plan plan ) {
    Plan p = Objects.requireNonNullElse ( plan , Plan.BASIC_PLAN ) ;  // No exception involved.
    …
}
```

Or you may want to dynamically locate a fall-back value to use as a default when encountering a NULL. You pass a method reference or a lambda function that, when executed, will return a substitute object as default.

```
public void doIt( Plan plan ) {
    Plan p = Objects.requireNonNullElseGet ( plan , DatabaseService::getDefaultPlan ) ;  // No exception involved.
    …
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Its based on your Project requirement. if you just return without throwing any exception user cant identify why that function is not executed and it makes confusion in user point of view.

if you showing alert or message these exception it should be better for those case. otherwise you should follow that input validation properly.

Comment: This also looks logical, any explanation about why this argument is not valid?